# How to have telegram bot post messages to my channel and not its own channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot which publishes messages to somebot using this code.

```
import telegram
from telegram import ParseMode
def send_msg(text):
    token = '1*****:AAF*************esns'
    chat_id = "34*****4"
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
    
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=text, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
```

What I was wondering is if it is possible for the telegram bot to send message to my channel where i have made it an admin and not its own channel called somebot.

Comment: @sajjadrezaei He mentioned that the Bot is already an Admin of the channel ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As your Bot already is an Admin of the channel you want it to post in, you just need to change the `chat_id` for `Bot.send_message()` to the one of the channel the bot is meant to send posts in.

You can obtain this ID for example by using [Bgram Telegram client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.BifToGram) or [IDBot](https://t.me/myidbot). Be aware that you may have to prepend `-100` to the ID you get as channels are just special super-groups.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I am using a channel called: `GETID BOT` in telegram. And if i forward message from any of my channel. its showing the same ID

Comment: What do you mean by showing the same ID? You send a message from multiple channels, but all have the same channel id?

Comment: What do you mean by "prepend -100" ? Example?

Comment: Some ids of chats have to start with -100, so my channel with id 123456 will have to be -100123456 if it's a public channel. you may also try alternative telegram clients like exteraGram to get chat ids.